# How to replace leading and ending tab but preserver middle code format?

Tags: php, preg-replace, str-replace

I am making a shrotcode that returns a pre output to demonstrate shortcode usage. 
It works fine but I need to trim the first and last tab from the output.

Example http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/365e7e96c760c453863ccd83f6e0b2215f64d416

```
$string ='  <pre>
    <ul>
        <li>Coffee</li>
        <li>Milk</li>
    </ul>
    </pre>
';

$get_pre = str_replace("\t","",$string);

echo $get_pre."\n" ;
echo $string ;
```

those will output

```
<pre>
<ul>
<li>Coffee</li>
<li>Milk</li>
</ul>
</pre>

    <pre>
    <ul>
        <li>Coffee</li>
        <li>Milk</li>
    </ul>
    </pre>
```

but I need

```
<pre>
<ul>
    <li>Coffee</li>
    <li>Milk</li>
</ul>
</pre>
```

Note that code can be any html so I cant target specifics like get ul or something like that. 
Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$str = preg_replace('~^\t~m', '', $str);
```

The m modifier changes the meaning of the `^` anchor that matches the start of the line.

Note: if you want to remove trailing spaces for each lines at the same time, you can change the pattern to:

```
$str = preg_replace('~^\t|[^\S\r\n]+$~m', '', $str);
```

Comment: you seen that one to didn't you :) nice. thnx again!

Answer (score 2):

You want `trim`

```
$string=trim($string,"\t");
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php

Comment: I thought so as well but is not removing the last one , see here 
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4e70ff813f871bbd4c4783a447b3960f9887cc24

Comment: Just because there is a new line at the end, so the \t won't be trimmed. The code should be $string=trim($string,"\t\n\r"); Maybe in the end, you should use $string = trim($string);